# android emulator-arm.exe needs to close

Tags: android, emulation

I updated my Android sdk  to r14(4.0).when i open emulator i am getting error

**emulator-arm.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the  inconvenience.**

please help me to clear this problem.

Comment: I faced the same issue, but only when I start AVD manager through eclipse. When AVD Manager.exe in android-sdks folder is used to launch the emulator, it starts normally.

Answer (score 0):

This seams to be a common Windows problem. I found [this blog-post](http://8thstring.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-emulator-armexe-crashing-in.html) (not that outdated) which illustrates how to install the AVD probably.

Comment: as per that blog " does not include any spaces and that the individual folder length is less than or equal to eight characters ".i dont have any spaces  in path, and it was workinfg fine befor update SDK

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem and I changed data in Memory Option >> RAM from 512 to 1024. It solved the problem